# BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm having issues getting a binding to work, I know the property exists but for some reason WPF cannot find it. Turning on tracing and i get the following errors

```
    System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'DefaultInBaseObject' property not found on 'object' ''GcBaseBuildingProperties' (HashCode=971734)'. 
BindingExpression:Path=DefaultInBaseObject; DataItem='GcBaseBuildingProperties' (HashCode=971734); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=DefaultInBaseObject; DataItem='GcBaseBuildingProperties' (HashCode=971734);
 target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')


System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value.
BindingExpression:Path=DefaultInBaseObject; DataItem='GcBaseBuildingProperties' (HashCode=971734); target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')
```

i'm building the binding in code with the following:

```
  DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate
        {
            DataType = data.GetType()
        };

        FrameworkElementFactory spFactory = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
        spFactory.Name = "Test";
        spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Vertical);
        spFactory.SetValue(StackPanel.DataContextProperty, data);


        //It starts pretty much the same as usual, we get a collection of all the fields in the NMSTemplate.
        IOrderedEnumerable<FieldInfo> fields = data.GetType().GetFields().OrderBy(field => field.MetadataToken);
        if (fields != null)
        {
            //We then loop over all those fields.
            foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in fields)
            {
                var attributes = (NMSAttribute[])fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NMSAttribute), false);                        //
                libMBIN.Models.NMSAttribute attrib = null;                                                                          //
                if (attributes.Length > 0) attrib = attributes[0];                                                                  //
                bool ignore = false;                                                                                                //
                if (attrib != null) ignore = attrib.Ignore;                                                                         //

                if (!ignore)                                                                                                        // Add the field to the mbinContents list
                {
                    FrameworkElementFactory Label = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
                    Label.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, fieldInfo.Name);
                    Label.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, fieldInfo.Name);
                    spFactory.AppendChild(Label);

                    FrameworkElementFactory cardHolder = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
                    cardHolder.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding(fieldInfo.Name));
                    cardHolder.SetValue(TextBlock.ToolTipProperty, fieldInfo.Name);
                    spFactory.AppendChild(cardHolder);
                }
            }
            dt.VisualTree = spFactory;
        }
        return dt;
```

I've stepped through and ensured that the context is correct, that the object is there and that it contains the property.

Unfortunatly i don't really understand these error/messages. Could someone explain them?

Comment: Hi. Having a real need of building DataTemplate in code is rare in WPF. It's usually people coming from other technologies that try to do that, instead of creating the DataTemplate in XAML. I believe this may be the case, as you don't understand these errors. Also - think of your code maintainers, it'll be even harder for them, to fix it or expand.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, The reason i'm building this is code is due to object ignorance. I'm building the template dynamically using reflection so i can't build the template in xaml because the property names/types are unknown at designtime. I've been using WPF for quite some time i just can't work out the issues here.

Answer (score 0):

The binding errors you have are probably because you want to bind to a field, while you can bind to properties only.

If you want to make the code better, while still dynamic, you can e.g.:

1. Read the data in your view model, then use ExpandoObject as the
   DataContext,
2. In XAML use ItemsContainer not a StackPanel (it's a kind of WPF code smell),
3. To have a dynamic TextBox, which has a possibility to
   bind by property name, create a UserControl, which exposes string
   Name, and does the dynamic binding when this property is set. Then
   use this UserControl in XAML. (You can also extend TextBlock instead of creating a UserControl).

It'll be much easier to understand, debug and test such a code.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. i can't believe it but your right, i made a stupid mistake when i glanced at the class and saw 'Public string Name;' and assume it was a property.